# Can if statements be nested in a while loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I've been working with code that uses a do-while loop, and I wanted to add an if else statement into that loop. The do-while loop checks to see what text the user enters and will finish if the word 'exit' is entered.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String endProgram = "exit";
    String userInput;
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        userInput = input.nextLine();
        if ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) ) {
            System.out.printf("You entered the following: %s", userInput);
        } else

    } while ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) );

}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get an error from the command prompt saying:

```
SentinelExample.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
            } while ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) );
            ^
SentinelExample.java:22: error: while expected
      }
       ^
SentinelExample.java:24: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
```

When I remove the if else statement in the loop, the program compiles fine. Is there something wrong with the syntax in my program? Or is it not possible to put an if else statement in a while loop?

Comment: *Can if statements be nested in a while loop?* yes

Comment: You have a useless else keyword there

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help everyone. Just wanted to know, why did my question get voted down?

Comment: @KylerS no offense to you but sometimes questions that are very simple get downvoted, generally I try to upvote an question I answer

Comment: @aaronman Alright, hey none taken. I'm new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code here you are missing `else` block:

```
    userInput = input.nextLine();
    if ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) ) {
        System.out.printf("You entered the following: %s", userInput);
    } else
```

This is the reason for the compilation error.  You can fix this by either removing the `else` altogether or if you want to add something in it then do the following:

```
    userInput = input.nextLine();
    if ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) ) {
        System.out.printf("You entered the following: %s", userInput);
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
```

And to answer your questions, yes it's perfectly valid to nest `if` statements in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `{}` to close the else block. Instead of

```
do{
  if(){
  }else
}while()
```

use

```
do{
  if(){
  }else{
  }
}while()
```

Answer (score 0):

That because of your else statment that does nothing but make the complier think that the while condition is under the else condition and that wrong.
Just remove it

Answer (score 0):

Its quite possible:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String endProgram = "exit";
    String userInput;
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        userInput = input.nextLine();
        if ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) ) {
            System.out.printf("You entered the following:"+userInput);// use plus ssign instead of %s
        }

    } while ( !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram) );

}
```

Comment: @SusanYanders : what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
package second;

public class Even {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=0;
        while (a<=100)
        {
            if (a%2==0)
            {
                System.out.println("The no is EVEN : " + a);
            }
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("The num is ODD : " + a);    
            }

        } } }
```

why this isn't working rightly, it only display the 0, with even !

Comment: Because you are using the while statement wrong. What you want to do should be done with a for-loop, like "for (int a = 0; a<=100; a++)".